# Переходы между активити, как определить с какого активити был переход в текущее?

Tags: android, activity

Переходы между активити, как определить с какого активити был переход в текущее?

Answer (score 0):

"Из коробки" - никак.

Как вариант, вы можете в [передавать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) некий идентификатор активности с которой стартуете новое.